# How to create a list of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have an array of pairs of values somewhat like this:

```
 let myarr = [[1, 'a'],
              [2, 'b'],
              [3, 'c']]
```

and one like this:

```
let otherArr = [5,6,7]
```

and I would like to convert them to an object which would be of the form:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":5,
         "pair":[
            1,
            "a"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":6,
         "pair":[
            2,
            "b"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":7,
         "pair":[
            3,
            "c"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

As a first attempt

I tried to use a `for` loop and tried to create a list of the `pair` keys like this

```
for (let pair = 0; pair < myarr.length; pair++) {
  myobj[pair].pair = myarr[pair]
```

and I get an error stating `TypeError: Cannot set property 'pair' of undefined`

Is there a efficient way to create a object like the example above
Thanks in advance

Comment: So just to point out logic flaws, your stated desired json consists of an object with a single key of "data".  Where is that part in your logic?

Comment: Look up how to zip two objects

Comment: (That was a suggestion, not an order)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your for loop fails is because you need to instantiate an object before you can set properties on it.  For example, you could use `Array.push` to iterate over your array and create new objects at each index.

```
const myobj = { data: [] };
for (let index = 0; index < myarr.length; index++) {
    myobj.data.push({ pair: myarr[index], id: otherArr[index]})
}
```

A shorter way to write the above, assuming that `myarra` and `otherArr` will always have the same length, would be to use `Array.map` to iterate over your first array and return a new one of the same length.

`const myobj = { 
    data: myArra.map((pair, index) => ({ pair, id: otherArr[index] }) 
}`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
let otherArr = [5,6,7];

let myarr = [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']];

let obj = { "data":[] };

otherArr.map((item, index) => {
 obj.data.push({
   "id": item,
    "pair": myarr[index]
  })
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```js
 let myarr = [[1, 'a'],
              [2, 'b'],
              [3, 'c']];
let otherArr = [5,6,7];

let data = myarr.map((i,idx) => {

    return {
        "id": otherArr[idx],
        "pair": i
    };

});

console.log({data});
```